# Help installing Retropie on Pi Zero

Tags: pi-zero, retropie

This is my first time ever working with Pis, so I know pretty much Zero about them. I'm trying to build a gaming system so I don't have to buy that outrageous SNES mini, nor do I want to buy a prebuilt system because I want to fix it if anything goes wrong. I keep hitting a dead end, but here's what I know:

- It's a Zero with Version 1.3 on the back (according to Adafruit)
- I'm using a 64g PNY SD card (formatted to FAT I think) and has the retropie image installed on the disk.
- I'm using a turbo charger for power supply, so I don't think it's a power issue.
- When I connect it to a TV, it goes from the standard "No Input" message to a black screen, so the TV's reading something. However, it just stays black - no booting, no code showing up, nothing.
- The green LED flashes, then either stays solid or does a very intermittent flashing.

Is the SD card too big? Is it the wrong format? Is there something else I haven't taken into account?

Comment: How is the Pi connected to the TV ?

Comment: To be sure : did you install your image on the SD card by writting it with a specific software, or just by copying the .img file on it ? The second method won't work ;)

Comment: Mike: I have a mini hdmi/hdmi adapter with an hdmi cable running to the TV.

Comment: Technico: I wrote it onto the sd card with Win32 disk imager.

Comment: It sounds like you turned it on, and then plugged in HDMI.  Have you turned it on with the HDMI already connected?  Might try burning another image (like raspbian) with "Etcher".  Then go back to retropie if that works.

Comment: Hi Red, I've tried both ways and only got a black screen when it was already plugged in. I'll try raspbian and Etcher later today, thanks!